# MapFragment gets a dark overlay when used in DialogActivity

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I'm trying to show a `MapFragment` of the `Android Maps v2 API` in an `Activity` with the `@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar` theme. This works fine. However, the map gets a dark overlay:

[image: Dialog]

When I change the theme to `@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar`, the map is shown as it should:

[image: Normal]

This is my xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapfragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="HELLO"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_large" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What is happening here?

Comment: Maybe it helps you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126594/mapfragment-styled-as-dialog-causes-textview-to-be-transparent.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got the same problem. After some research, I found two hacks :

- Add this param for your theme in the styles.xml :
  `<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>`

Bad part : it removes the black overlays behind the activity.

- Set the z order on the top for the map object :
  `GoogleMapOptions googleMapsOptions = new GoogleMapOptions();

  googleMapsOptions.zOrderOnTop( true );

  MapFragment mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance(googleMapsOptions);`

Bad part : The map is above the Zoom control and MyLocation button.

Personnaly, I choose the first solution.
Hope this help !

[Link to the source](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4865)

Answer (score 11):

For `DialogFragment`:

```
getDialog().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

Comment: While the code may answer the question, it would be better to explain _how_ it works and _why_ to use it.

Comment: This solution is useful for transparent activities that already have a dimmed background (which does not interfere with Google Maps), especially as the default `DialogFragment` dimmed background is useless, and makes it too dark

Answer (score 1):

To add on to [Audrel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16188173/836540), one can dynamically un-dim the dialog's window whenever the map is shown and dim it back when the map is gone (e.g. when your dialog has multiple pages, one of them is a map):

```
private float mDimAmount;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
    mDimAmount = params.dimAmount; // remember original dim amount
    ...
}

private void undim() {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.dimAmount = 0.0f;
    getWindow().setAttributes(params);
}

private void dim() {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.dimAmount = mDimAmount;
    getWindow().setAttributes(params);
}
```

Still just another workaround rather than tackling the root cause...

Comment: Thank you for sharing, I think this should be added: `getWindow().setAttributes(params); `

Comment: BTW, I use AMap from China, I guess GoogleMap already fixed this issue long time ago, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your purpose is for the map in the dialog, if you don't need any of the map controls, you can use `liteMode` in which just an image of the map is displayed with whatever location you load. It doesn't have this z-layer overlay problem.

You can add this to the `MapView` layout xml:

`map:liteMode="true"`

This worked for me, because I didn't want my map to be interactive anyway.

You can read the Google docs here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/lite

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this line to your **style** !

```
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
```

This is my style :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```